# Un-set button on refresh with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am making a calculator that will display the results on the same page, but when I refresh the button is still 'set' according to php.
I have a function running to catch the refresh and stop such things in javascript for something else I was doing but I am not sure how to 'un-set' the button on refresh.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  hide();
});
function hide() {
    var x = document.getElementById('drinksDIV');
    x.style.display = 'none';
    var x = document.getElementById('submit');
    x.session_unset;
}
function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID)
{
    document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable
}
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('drinksDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

But when I refresh the echo'd results still remain at the top

This is what i have at the top of my page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //check if form was submitted
  $input = $_POST['age']; //get input text
  echo "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}    
?>
```

Once submitted once it will always be there instead of hiding on refresh

Comment: DOM elements do not have a property called `session_unset`... what is that?

Comment: You say refresh, I assume you are refreshing the page. That being said, the code you have at the top is if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ and you are saying that this is still returning true which is in turn echoing "Success! You entere..", my first question is are you resubmitting the info when refreshing the page ( does a pop up box show saying do you wish to resubmit the form )? Sorry to ask just trying to eliminate this as a possibility.

Comment: No popup I can see, I an ctrl+f5ing but if I use an incognito window the first run will be fresh again

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want anything to show on your page after your PHP code is executed, you can do this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //check if form was submitted    
  $input = $_POST['age']; //get input text
  echo "Success! You entered: ".$input;
  die();
}    
?>
```

Note the `die()` function called after the echo.

Comment: All the does is prevent using the form altogether after one input on a fresh page